# why can't my function pass the testing code?

Tags: javascript

```
function checkNumber(cardNumber) {

   var prefix = cardNumber.slice(0,2);
   if ((prefix === '38' || prefix === '39') && cardNumber.length === 14) {
        return 'Diner\'s Club';
   } else if ((prefix === '34' || prefix === '37') && cardNumber.length === 15) {
        return 'American Express';
   }
}
```

The function takes a string of Credit card number and return its netWork Name. EX : Diner's Club network always starts with a 38 or 39 and is 14 digits long...... and American Express network always starts with a 34 or 37 and is 15 digits long. The function returns the correct output.

My question is why when I use a testing environment, the code does not pass. it says:
"you should try your function for EVERY combination of length and prefix and make sure it returns the correct network."
what does that mean? Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: It is because if input starts with anything other than 34,37,38,39 then your function does not return anything. Please add one more `else` block to return for all other cases

Comment: @AhmadZughayyer — And what does the test look like?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your function is incomplete. Whatever testing environment you're using is executing some tests on things other than the two options you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

What is this "code testing" you speak of? An application?

Your function does not have a `return` if one of the first two conditions are not met.

Try this:

```
function checkNumber(cardNumber) {

   var prefix = cardNumber.slice(0,2);
   if ((prefix === '38' || prefix === '39') && cardNumber.length === 14) {
        return 'Diner\'s Club';
   } else if ((prefix === '34' || prefix === '37') && cardNumber.length === 15) {
        return 'American Express';
   }
   else 
   {
      return "Unknown Card"; 
   }
}
```

Or this (probably better):

```
function checkNumber(cardNumber) {

   var prefix = cardNumber.slice(0,2);
   if ((prefix === '38' || prefix === '39') && cardNumber.length === 14) {
        return 'Diner\'s Club';
   } else if ((prefix === '34' || prefix === '37') && cardNumber.length === 15) {
        return 'American Express';
   }
   return "Unknown Card"; 
}
```